# Are GPIO outputs software or hardware controlled?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-theory

I’m trying to diagnose an iPhone 6s that’s stuck in a boot loop. iTunes error points to a baseband issue.

So I’ve compared to a known working board and found that the PMU_TO_BB_PMIC_RESET_L line (at Resistor R2200) should be high at 1.8v but when I measure it’s very momentary high then quickly drops and stays low at 0v

Tracing the line it’s an out from the GPIO section of the main power ic for the entire phone

I have no other literature or information on how the circuit’s supposed to function so I’m here asking to hopefully gather any information that may help me determine what’s going on

If GPIO outputs are software controlled then I need to figure out what parameters are causing it to go low and stay low.

Apologies in advance if I’m not supposed to ask “troubleshooting” questions but I need to get data off this phone and my last resort is seeking help here[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely software, but you can never tell without the datasheet. Timer control is quite possible.

Comment: Timer control? If I remove R2200 the line stays high at 1.8v but phone still boot loops and the baseband PMU doesn’t output any voltages

Comment: Assuming the line isn't loaded by a near-short, this is not something you can approach from first principles - instead, try an iphone repair forum where you can find people with domain expertise of the particular system you are trying to repair.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that’s the problem, I’ve tried but people on those forums seem to have very little knowledge about the working principles of electronics on an advanced level

Comment: Your question (or at least the useful question you should be asking) isn't actually about the working principles of electronics, instead it is specifically about the behavior of the iPhone.  And for that you need advice from experienced iphone repair technicians - not *design* engineers (unless you find the one who actually designed this).  Try somehwere like this: http://forum.mendonipadrehab.com/

Comment: I don't think any "experienced iphone repairmen" can be of any help here. It looks like the phone PMIC has experienced some power rail problem, and the PMIC microcode asserts some block reset. Maybe only two-three people in the entire Apple company know this algorithm and specifications for this particular model, and the actual coders in Asia were likely fired long ago. The repairmen "solution" is usually the only one - replace the entire mainboard.